# Open a file, modify every char then do the reverse operation doesn't output the original file

Tags: c++, file, char, fstream

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    // compress

    std::ifstream inFile("test.input");
    std::ofstream outFile("test.compressed");
    char c;

    while(inFile >> c)
        outFile << c + 1;

    // decompress

    std::ifstream inFile2("test.compressed");
    std::ofstream outFile2("test.output");

    while(inFile2 >> c)
        outFile2 << c - 1;

    // close

    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();
    inFile2.close();
    outFile2.close();

    return 0;
}
```

That is my code. There is probably something I haven't understood, because for me `test.input` should be the same as `test.output` but they're not.

Comment: If you are going to open an `ifstream` to a file you already have a `ofstream` handle to, flush it first. Call `outFile.flush()` before starting anything related to decompression.

Comment: Please be aware the the underlying OS and the filesystem may or may not flush all the data to you r first temporary output file "test.compressed" by the time you open it for reading.

Comment: Better yet, don't keep objects around for longer than needed. Enclose the compression code in braces (or move to another function), then do the same for the decompression code. Also, you can rely on the stream destructors to close the files that way, no need for explicit calls to `close`.

Comment: What does 'do the reverse operation' mean?

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems here. First, when you add (or subtract) a `char` from an `int`, the result is an `int`. So calculating `c + 1` will be written as digits to `test.compressed` (e.g., `'a'`'s ASCII code is `97`. So after adding `1` to it you'd get `98`, which would be written to the file as the characters `'9'` and `'8'`). You then subtract 1 from these characters, and obviously do not get the same output back. This can be solved by casting the result back down to a `char`.

The second problem is much more prosaic - you attempt to read from the file you've written to before flushing it, so you may be missing some (or all) of the data you've written. This can be solved by just closing the files once you're done with them, which is generally a good practice.

To put it all together:

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    // compress

    std::ifstream inFile("test.input");
    std::ofstream outFile("test.compressed");
    char c;

    while(inFile >> c)
        outFile << (char)(c + 1); // Casting to char

    // Close the files you're done with
    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();

    // decompress

    std::ifstream inFile2("test.compressed");
    std::ofstream outFile2("test.output");

    while(inFile2 >> c)
        outFile2 << (char)(c - 1); // You need the cast here too

    // Close the files you're done with
    inFile2.close();
    outFile2.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I thought that printing an integer into a file would consider it as a char. Though it still doesn't work and I don't get why: if I print the chars `std::cout << (char)(c + 1) << " ";` in the first `while` and `std::cout << (char)(c - 1) << " ";` in the second one, it doesn't display the same chars.

Comment: That's because you'd also be subtracting `1` from the spaces, while you aren't adding `1` to them. You need to skip the spaces when you read the file.

Comment: Well even without the `<< " "` the two `while` don't print the same thing.

Comment: @Jeremy Can you share an example input and output? The above code worked when I tested it with a trivial input (`abcdefg`).

Comment: I tried it with a .jpeg file as an input but it should work the same right? It's just bytes. Is it possible than one file considers the chars from -128 to 127 and the other from 0 to 255? Or if a char is at the upper bound, when I add +1 then -1, is it still at the upper bound?

Comment: @Jeremy don't use `char`s for binary data. change `c` to be an `int`, and you should be OK.

Comment: Why not? If I replace `char` by `int`, it doesn't even go into the `while` anymore.